# ROS Noetic: problem installer SLAM-TOOLBOX

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Problem: Raspberry Pi4 4GB with OS 20.04. Not install Slam-Toolbox with sudo apt ros-noetic-slam-toolbox.
Why?

Thanks!
Carlo

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd catkin_ws
pi@raspberrypi:~/cd catkin_ws $ sudo apt install ros-noetic-slam-toolbox
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto ros-noetic-slam-toolbox
pi@raspberrypi:~/cd catkin_ws $
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400922/ros-noetic:-problem-installer-slam-toolbox/) by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ParkerRobert](https://answers.ros.org/users/56923/parkerrobert/) on 2022-05-19**:
This may seem like a simple question, but have you tried `sudo apt install ros-noetic-slam-toolbox`? The word `install` is missing in the above question snippet

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
Thanks for the reply!

Tried **sudo apt install ros-noetic-slam-toolbox**, but same result: it doesn't find the installation package!

Carlo

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-20**:
Please add additional information either as a comment, or by editing your question.

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
No, sorry...

Carlo

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-20**:
That package [is available for Ubuntu Focal on ARMv8](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_ufv8.html?q=toolb), but whether you can install it using `apt` would depend on whether you've used `apt` to install ROS Noetic itself.

Did you use `apt` to install ROS Noetic, or did you build from source in a Catkin workspace?

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
I use apt for install ROS Noetic.
It is better to redo the whole installation (Ubuntu 20.04 +  ROS + SLAM-Toolbox)?

Carlo

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-20**:
Please show the *verbatim* output of `sudo apt install ros-noetic-slam-toolbox`. Do not paraphrase errors / output messages.

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
Et voilà! File dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxqt64936ku5l1e/photo1652972290.jpeg?dl=0

Carlo

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-20**:
Please do not use screenshots for this.

It's all text.

Just copy-paste it into your original question.

Use the `edit` button/link below it and append the new information.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-20**:
Please also add the output of `lsb_release -a`, `uname -a` and `sudo apt install ros-noetic-roscpp`.

Make sure to first run `sudo apt update` (as @Joe28965 suggests in his answer).

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
Sorry!

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd catkin_ws
pi@raspberrypi:~/cd catkin_ws $ sudo apt installa ros-noetic-slam-toolbox
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto ros-noetic-slam-toolbox
pi@raspberrypi:~/cd catkin_ws $

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
as@gvdhoorn

pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Raspbian

Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Release: 10

Codename: buster

pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ uname -a

Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ sudo apt install ros-noetic-roscpp

Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto

Generazione albero delle dipendenze

Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto

E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto ros-noetic-roscpp

pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-20**:
@carlo_paniccia please edit the question and paste this in the same way as gvdhoorn has done to your question. This is way too difficult for anybody to comfortably read.

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
I'm sorry I'm a neophyte ...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ sudo apt install ros-noetic-roscpp
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze      
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto ros-noetic-roscpp
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $
```

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-20**:
Could you give the output of `sudo apt update`?

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
output of `sudo apt update` is

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ sudo apt update
Trovato:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Trovato:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Trovato:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu buster InRelease
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze      
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
7 pacchetti possono essere aggiornati: eseguire "apt list --upgradable" per vederli.
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $
```

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
update...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ apt list --upgradable
Elencazione... Fatto
libpq5/oldstable 11.16-0+deb10u1 armhf [aggiornabile da: 11.14-0+deb10u1]
libssl-dev/oldstable 1.1.1n-0+deb10u2 armhf [aggiornabile da: 1.1.1n-0+deb10u1]
libssl1.1/oldstable 1.1.1n-0+deb10u2 armhf [aggiornabile da: 1.1.1n-0+deb10u1]
openssl/oldstable 1.1.1n-0+deb10u2 armhf [aggiornabile da: 1.1.1n-0+deb10u1]
python-catkin-pkg-modules/buster 0.5.0-1 all [aggiornabile da: 0.4.24-1]
python3-catkin-pkg-modules/buster 0.5.0-1 all [aggiornabile da: 0.4.24-1]
python3-catkin-pkg/buster 0.5.0-100 all [aggiornabile da: 0.4.24-100]
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Raspberry Pi4 4GB with OS 20.04

We apparently all assumed `20.04` meant Ubuntu (which it typically does).

You are however running Raspbian, which is based on Debian Buster:

> ```
> Distributor ID: Raspbian
> ```

```
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster
```

That's not `20.04`, nor Ubuntu.

Debian Buster only gets packages for ARMv8, but on that platform, according to [status_page/ros_noetic_dbv8.html?q=toolb](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_dbv8.html?q=toolb), `ros-noetic-slam-toolbox` is *intentionally* not available.

There are no binary packages available for Debian Buster ARMhf (v7, hard-float) at all, therefore, you cannot install `slam_toolbox` using `apt`.

Note: it is available for ARMhf for Ubuntu Focal: [status_page/ros_noetic_ufhf.html?q=toolb](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_ufhf.html?q=toolb). But that would require you to reinstall your OS.

---

Edit: I'm rather confused by your statement:

> I use apt for install ROS Noetic.

and:

> ```
> Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
> ```

Afaict, this would be impossible. Only ARMv8 gets binary packages on Debian Buster.

---

Edit 2: did you perhaps install ROS using the [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages)? If so, please read that page and be aware of the limitations/impact.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-20**:
Just to answer a potential future question. If you do want to use `slam_toolbox` you could use a laptop and run it on there, connecting both laptop and raspberry to the same network and configure them to discover each other.

**Comment by [carlo.paniccia](https://answers.ros.org/users/105336/carlo.paniccia/) on 2022-05-20**:
Sorry ... which SLAM do you recommend for Raspbian, which is based on Debian Buster?

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-20**:
Both `gmapping` and `hector_slam` seem to be available.